# Incorporating Animation into insertUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinyanimate

I have the following code as part of my app:

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)

#ui----
ui = basicPage(
  actionButton("show", "Create a New Analysis")
)

#server----    
server = function(input, output, session) {

  #Show modal when button is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(dataModal())
  })

  #dataModal----    
  #The main modal dialog function. Sets the initial buttons shown on the dialog.
  dataModal <- function() {
    modalDialog(
      h2("Analysis Setup", align = "center"),
      h4("Choose a Setting of Care:", align = "center"),

      #Level0----
      #Inpatient button. The HTML function (i.e. div, style) is used to evenly space
      #the buttons in the dialog window.
      div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: center;",
          popify(actionButton("Inpatientz", "Inpatient", icon("user-md")),
                 "Inpatient",
                 "Dialogue 1.")),

      #Emergency button. The HTML function (i.e. div, style) is used to evenly space
      #the buttons in the dialog window.
      div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: center;",
          popify(bsButton("Emergencyz", HTML("Emergency <br> Department"), icon("ambulance"), style = "default", size = "default"),
                 "Emergency",
                 "Dialogue 2.")),

      #Ambulatory button. The HTML function (i.e. div, style) is used to evenly space
      #the buttons in the dialog window.          
      div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: center;",
          popify(bsButton("Ambulatoryz", HTML("Ambulatory <br> Surgery"), icon("medkit"), style = "default", size = "default"),
                 "Ambulatory",
                 "Dialogue 3.")),

      tags$div(id = 'placeholder'), 
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      ),
      #easyClose is an argument which allows the user to click outside the
      #dialog window or press the escape key to close the dialog window.
      easyClose = TRUE
    )
  }
  #Level1----     
  observeEvent(input$Inpatientz, {

    #Adds Descriptive Statistics button with popover.
    insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
             ui = bsButton("Descriptivez", "Descriptive Statistics", style = "default", size = "default"), immediate = TRUE
                         )
    addPopover(session, "Descriptivez", "Descriptive Statistics", "Quote 1")
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$Emergencyz, {

    #Adds Trends button with popover.
    insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
             ui = bsButton("Trendsz", "Trends", style = "default", size = "default")
                         ,  immediate = TRUE)
    addPopover(session, "Trendsz", "Trends", "Quote 2")
  })

  observeEvent(input$Ambulatoryz, {

    #Adds Rank button with popover.
    insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
             ui = bsButton("Rankz", "Rank", style = "default", size = "default"), immediate = TRUE)

    addPopover(session, "Rankz", "Rank", "Quote 3")
  })



  #Close Modal
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

which pops up a new button (either Descriptive, Trends, or Rank) in response to the user response (by clicking Inpatient, Emergency, or Ambulatory). I would like these new buttons to appear with an animation, such as those available under the `shinyanimate` or `shinyjqui` packages. However, I'm running into the problem where `jqui_add/jqui_remove/startAnim 1`) requires that I already have created the UI beforehand and 2) cannot allow me to add an object in the modal window using the selective argument that is possible under `insertUI`. Is there a way to incorporate the animation features into `insertUI` that allows me to bypass these issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but just answering so that it would help anyone who stumble across this in future.

You can incorporate Animation into `insertUI` using `shinyanimate`.

**Disclaimer: I am the author of shinyanimate package**

Here is a minimal example from the code snippet you provided above:

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)
library(shinyanimate)

#ui----
ui = basicPage(
  withAnim(),
  actionButton("show", "Create a New Analysis")
)

#server----    
server = function(input, output, session) {

  #Show modal when button is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(dataModal())
  })

  #dataModal----    
  #The main modal dialog function. Sets the initial buttons shown on the dialog.
  dataModal <- function() {
    modalDialog(
      h2("Analysis Setup", align = "center"),
      h4("Choose a Setting of Care:", align = "center"),

      #Level0----
      #Inpatient button. The HTML function (i.e. div, style) is used to evenly space
      #the buttons in the dialog window.
      div(style="display:inline-block;width:32%;text-align: center;",
          popify(actionButton("Inpatientz", "Inpatient", icon("user-md")),
                 "Inpatient",
                 "Dialogue 1.")),

      tags$div(id = 'placeholder'), 
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      ),
      #easyClose is an argument which allows the user to click outside the
      #dialog window or press the escape key to close the dialog window.
      easyClose = TRUE
    )
  }
  #Level1----     
  observeEvent(input$Inpatientz, {

    #Adds Descriptive Statistics button with popover.
    insertUI(selector = '#placeholder',
             ui = bsButton("Descriptivez", "Descriptive Statistics", style = "default", size = "default"), immediate = TRUE
             )
    startAnim(session, 'Descriptivez', 'bounce')
    # addPopover(session, "Descriptivez", "Descriptive Statistics", "Quote 1")
  }) 

  #Close Modal
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```